# Datagrid set edit mode on and off based on cell click in data grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF datagrid and by default i have set the edit mode off.
I have an update icon on the data grid, and when i click on the update icon on each row, i want the edit mode to set to on and first cell of the data grid should be focused.

```
  <DataGrid  Grid.Row="2" Name="dgList" Margin="0,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding List,Mode=TwoWay}" RowHeight="40" ColumnWidth="*"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" MouseLeftButtonDown="dgList_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
              PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="dgList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" > 
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" MinWidth="250" IsReadOnly="True">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource ucconvertToImage}}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="250" Binding="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Active" MinWidth="250" Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Update"  MinWidth="50" MaxWidth="50" SortMemberPath="EditMode" IsReadOnly="False">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="Icons/Update.jpg">
                                        </Image>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

I want to check if i click on update icon, first check if it is the update column and then set the isreadonly as true.
I use the following code to do so, however, i get the sender as the entire datagrid not the cell.

```
 private void dgList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
            if (cell != null)
            {
                dgList.IsReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
```

How can i set the data grid property to edit mode on for one row, on click of update icon on that row.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Please narrow down to a specific problem. Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

To set Edit/ReadOnly mode of the `DataGrid` (**dgList**) you do not need to click on cell: just have a single `ChecBox` (e.g. named **chkEdit**) outside the `DataGrid` and add the event handle like follows:

```
chkEdit.Click+=()=>{dgList.IsReadOnly = !(bool)chkEdit.IsChecked; };
```

Regards,

Comment: The requirement is to have an update icon on each row of the grid.

Comment: Then it probably should be dgList.IsReadOnly = false; in order to allow edits. Rgds,